# Thread was being aborted in form.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, render

I am using form.Render method for some working.
Some times it troughs an error.

### Message

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
at DTrnsForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
```

I don't know which line is giving this error.
I am not using any kind of Response.Redirect in my code.
But i am using

### Code used

```
Response.Write("");
Response.Flush();
```

Can any one tell me what is the problem and how can i solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Response.Redirect and facing this problem then just

### Use

```
Response.Redirect("",false);
```

If you are not using Response.Redirect and still facing this problem.
Then just add in your web.config

### Code

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110"/>
</system.web>
```

My problem is solved by changing in web.config